# Get values from complex Array of Dictionary in Swift2

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift2

I'm displaying a dictionary as UITableView. I did this very easily in Objective- c . But now in swift, I cannot get values from array of dictionary. When I try to get values in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` the precompiler throw error like

> Cannot convert value of type "AnyObject?!" to specified type 'Array'

or like in this example below

> Cannot convert value of type "AnyObject?!" with an idnex of type 'int'

```
var cellArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    cellArray = [
        [
            "section" : "Melody",
            "rows" :
                [
                    [
                        "title" : "Wi-Fi / Pairing",
                        "icon" : "",
                        "action" : "actionConnectSpeaker"
                    ],
                    [
                        "title" : "Sound",
                        "icon" : "",
                        "action" : "actionConnectSpeaker"
                    ]
                ]
        ],

        [
            "section" : "Music",
            "rows" :
                [
                    [
                        "title" : "Add a new account",
                        "icon" : "",
                        "action" : "actionAddAccount"
                    ]
                ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellArray[indexPath.section]["rows"][indexPath.row]["title"]


    return cell
}
```

I conclude we cannot do like this... I find any example. I probably not understand something about Types in Swift ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift you have to downcast `AnyObject` types if you want to call functions like `objectAtIndex:` or `objectForKey:` what subscripting actually does.

```
let section = cellArray[indexPath.section]
let rows = section["rows"] as! [[String:String]]
cell.textLabel?.text = rows[indexPath.row]["title"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing this if you're sure there's no `nil` value:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = cellArray[indexPath.section]["rows"]![indexPath.row]["title"]
```

Comment: check the answer above. Your answer answers to an other problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it safely (if any object can be nil or the other type, you should use `if let`:

```
if let dict = cellArray[indexPath.section] as? [String : AnyObject],
    rows = dict["rows"] as? [AnyObject], 
    result = rows[indexPath.row] as? [String : AnyObject],
    title = result["title"] {
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generally avoid collections with elements of different types in Swift. Your section data is a dictionary, the value of "section" key is a string while the value of "rows" key is an array. Try to replace this dictionary with a tuple.

```
var cellArray = [(String, [[String: String]])]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    cellArray = [
        (
            "Melody",
            [
                [
                    "title" : "Wi-Fi / Pairing",
                    "icon" : "",
                    "action" : "actionConnectSpeaker"
                ],
                [
                    "title" : "Sound",
                    "icon" : "",
                    "action" : "actionConnectSpeaker"
                ]
            ]
        ),

        (
            "Music",
            [
                [
                    "title" : "Add a new account",
                    "icon" : "",
                    "action" : "actionAddAccount"
                ]
            ]
        )
    ]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellArray[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]["title"]

    return cell
}
```

This way Swift's type system can help you make sure you are using the right type, no force downcasting is needed.